# Statistical problem involving a coin

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Two friends flip a coin $100$ times, and $58$ it is head. One says the coin is rigged, the other says it is not, and that it happened by chance. The problem asks to verify the hypothesis $p=1/2$ versus $p \neq1/2$, and who should I believe. He then asks to do the same in a situation with $1000$ throws and $580$ heads.

I know I am supposed to use De Moivre-Laplace approximation, but in the result it says that in the first case the coin is not rigged starting from level $0.011$ approximately, while in the other case you have to refute the hypothesis. What does that level mean, in fact? And how do I find that number?

The approach I want to take is define 100 Bernoulli variables $X_i$ and take their mean $Y$. I know that the expected value is 50 (under the hypothesis $p=1/2$), so I think you should do something like $P\{|Y-50|<8\}>1- \alpha$. That is, find $\alpha$ manipulating the inequality to use De Moivre-Laplace. But in fact I don’t know if this is the correct approach, I am used to unilateral tests, but not to these...

Comment: Is it " the coin is  not rigged starting from level 0.11 approximately" and not .011?

Comment: Yes, 0.011. But maybe there are typos in the solution, idk

Comment: I mean, I just want to understand how to approach these kind of problems

Comment: Please tell us more about the context in which you're dealing with this problem. For instance, if you wanted to take a Bayesian approach, there's not enough information to answer the question. It sounds like you want to perform a standard frequentist point hypothesis test?

Comment: @joriki I edited the question. Idk if it helps, this is the first problem of this kind I have to deal with and I am actually quite confused on what I should do. However, I can say for sure that I should solve it using De Moivre-Laplace approximation an quantils of the normal distribution. I just don’t know how to use them in this situation.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the specific approach you want to take, but about the broader context you're operating in. Are you taking a particular course? Working with a particular book? Encountered the question in a contest? On a website? There are very different frameworks for hypothesis tests, and we need to know which framework you're working in.

Comment: This is an exercise from an exam of an introductory course about probability and statistics (university, not high school). I don’t follow any book, just the notes given by the teacher. About the framework, I am sorry I really can’t help you. As I said this is my very first “serious” course about these topics and I don’t know enough to explain what kind of approach I am doing, given that I only know one (and in this case, zero in fact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to proportion hypothesis testing which is the same as frequentist approach.

Hypothesis framework:

$H_0 : p = .5$

$H_1 : p \ne 0.5$

Use the z-statistic and find the p-value.  That p-value is the level above which the null hypothesis ( the coin is not rigged) is rejected.

z -statistic =$ \dfrac{\hat p - p_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}}$

$\hat p =\frac{58}{100} =0.58$  and $p_0 = \frac{50}{100} =0.5$

$p - value = 2*$(1-Normsdist(z-statistic))

Do the same for the other experiment involved with 1000 flips and you will see that the z-statistic is large and one would have to reject the null hypothesis that the coin in not rigged.

Comment: Wait, I think I understand what you do in the so called z-statistic. But what is $p_0$? Is it $50$? Also, $\hat{p}$ is 58? If so, this means that in these problems I should just calculate the area under the gaussian curve from the mean (50 in this case) up to the value I obtained (that is 58) and also in the other direction (so 42). Then 1 minus this area is the probability of obtaining more than 58 heads and less than 42. But when do you call this probability acceptable? I haven’t been given any level at the beginning of the exercise, so is it just common sense (1% acceptable, .00001% not)?

Comment: p hat is what you observed and p_0 is your claim.  n is the number of times the experiment was conducted. It is a two sided test.

Comment: If you have a level of significance given then you compare your p value which is the probability that you mentioned ( but not 58 and 42 but .58 and 0.42) with that of the level of significance and then make your conclusion about rejecting or not rejecting the null hypothesis which states that the coin is not rigged and that it is equal probable to have head as many number of times as a tail in the experiment

Comment: Ok, thanks. Last thing: what is Normdist? I usually use integral tables of normal distribution $\Phi$ to estimate that. It would be $2(1-\Phi(q))$ I think, with $q$ equal to the espression for the z-statistic.

Comment: You are correct  with your calculation and that is exactly what Normdist is which is $\Phi(q)$ (An EXCEL Term)

Comment: But if so, the result would be $0.11$. So I guess this is right, given that at first you asked me wheter the level was $0.11$. I guess there is a typo in the solutions given by the teacher, then.

Comment: You are right, there could be a typo in the answer. Good luck with your course .